# Is it possible to retrieve the history for a component via the Core Service?

Tags: core-service, 2013

I'm investigating certain operations against the Core Service for an upcoming project. I'm wondering whether its possible to retrieve the version history of a component via the Core Service? (As in, the items shown in the right-click context menu > Versioning > History).

I can retrieve the current version of any component, but can't see in the docs how I would retrieve previous versions, or a list of previous versions.

Here's the basic code I'm using to retrieve component data:

```
var component = (ComponentData) client.Read(componentId, 
    new ReadOptions {LoadFlags = LoadFlags.Expanded | LoadFlags.IncludeDynamicVersionInfo});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need something like this

```
VersionsFilterData versionsFilter = new VersionsFilterData();
IdentifiableObjectData[] versionList = client.GetList("tcm:7-15210", versionsFilter );
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about a list of versions but for a specific version: I believe you can append the version number onto the TCM ID. e.g. `tcm:3-120-v1` would get you version 1.

Comment: This works too, but as you say, its more for retrieving a specific version of an item, rather than a list of versions.